# How do I create a new list from a list template (Client Object Model)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating the list based on custom list template. List is creating, but the custom list template is not applied for my list.

```
ListTemplate template = null;
ListTemplateCollection ltc = context.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(context.Web);
context.Load(ltc);
context.ExecuteQuery();  

foreach (ListTemplate t in ltc)
{
    if (t.InternalName == "STPDiv.stp")
    {
        template = t;
        break;
     }
}

ListCreationInformation info = new ListCreationInformation();
info.Title = "TestCreation";
info.TemplateType = template.ListTemplateTypeKind;
info.TemplateFeatureId = template.FeatureId;           
info.QuickLaunchOption = QuickLaunchOptions.DefaultValue;
site.Lists.Add(info);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

How can my code be modified to get the custom list applied?

Comment: Firstly you're not null checking the template object, so you may well not have actually gotten the template you're after. Secondly that doesn't look like a list template name to me.

Answer (score 6):

Try this code given below. It should work for you. Let me know if you encounter any problem.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("<Your Site URL>");
Web site = context.Web;            
context.Load(site);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//Create a List.
ListCreationInformation listCreationInfo;
List list;

listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
listCreationInfo.Title = "<Your Title>";
listCreationInfo.Description = "<Your Description>";

var listTemplate = 
            site.ListTemplates.First(listTemp => listTemp.Name == "<Your Template Name>");
listCreationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;

list = site.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

**As per Microsoft :** [ListCreationInformation members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcreationinformation_members.aspx)

**TemplateFeatureId =** Gets or sets a value that specifies the feature identifier of the feature that contains the list schema for the new list

Comment: This one almost worked for me. All I needed to add was listCreationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;

Comment: This didn't work for me on an "Access App" list, and a few others. Also ClientContext implements IDisposable so be sure to use a "using" statement on the context object.