# List Template not getting applied to the new Sharepoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, console-application, sharepoint-list

A SharePoint list is being created using Sharepoint.client but the template is not getting applied. I don't see any fields/columns in the new list. A similar questions was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107570/how-do-i-create-a-new-list-from-a-list-template-client-object-model) but it's answer did not work for me. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(SITE))
        {
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            ListTemplate template = null;
            ListTemplateCollection ltc = context.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(web);
            //ListTemplateCollection ltc2 = web.ListTemplates;
            context.Load(ltc);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListTemplate t in ltc)
            {
                if (t.Name == "My_Template")
                {
                    template = t;
                    break;
                }
            }

            var listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation
            {
                Title = "Test_List",
                Description = "Test"
            }; 
            //ListTemplate listTemplate = ltc.First(listTemp => listTemp.Name.Contains("My_Template"));
            listCreationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = template.FeatureId;
            listCreationInfo.TemplateType = template.ListTemplateTypeKind;


            listCreationInfo.QuickLaunchOption = QuickLaunchOptions.On;                
            List oList = web.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

Comment: @Mr. Not yet! Tried many things but did not work.

Comment: after almost year no solution yet, I haven't had luck either. I think I will end doing the "template" by code, you know applying all the columns and views directly from code instead of a template. I had some external columns in my template that is the hard part

Comment: @Mr. I can't even do that because there is a workflow associated with that template. The workflow has lots of conditions which would require significant efforts from me to recreate it in my .NET code.